# Symfony3 forms not showing input fields when using CollectionType

Tags: twig, symfony

I'm having problem with displaying form when using CollectionType. It doesn't show newOrderCustomerType inputs, just label "Customer Id". Whats wrong?

[image]

newOrderCustomerType

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class newOrderCustomerType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->
        add('firstname', TextType::class,array('label'=>'Firstname'))->
        add('lastname', TextType::class,array('label'=>'Lastname'))->
        add('email', TextType::class,array('label'=>'Email'))->
        add('login', TextType::class,array('label'=>'Login'));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Customer',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'app_bundlenew_order_customer_type';
    }
}
```

newOrderType

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class newOrderType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('customerId',CollectionType::class,array(
                'entry_type'=>newOrderCustomerType::class,
                'allow_add'    => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Customer',
            ))
            ->add('shopOrderId')
            ->add('orderDate')
            ->add('postBuyFormMsg')
            ->add('invoice')
            ->add('payType')
            ->add('shipmentType')
            ->add('payStatus')
            ->add('save',SubmitType::class);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {

    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'app_bundlenew_order_type';
    }
}
```

And in TWIG template

```
{{ form_start(orderForm) }}
    {{ form_widget(orderForm) }}
{{ form_end(orderForm) }}
```

How to make it show all input fields?

Answer (score 2):

If you have an active "allow_add" option, it is possible to render this input throught the 'prototype' option:

```
 $builder
        ->add('customerId',CollectionType::class,array(
            'entry_type'=>newOrderCustomerType::class,
            'allow_add'    => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Customer',
            'prototype'     => true,
        ))
```

and then in the form:

```
{{ form_row(orderForm.customerId.vars.prototype}) }}
```

It should work.

For more, see the Symfony documentation of [prototype option](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#prototype)

Comment: Wow! it's been a year since that issue. I managed to find a work around.Anyway thanks for answer.

Comment: @hamzo your question is actual until now))

Answer (score 0):

Try removing 'data_class', I don't think that's part of CollectionType:

```
->add('customerId',CollectionType::class,array(
     'entry_type'=>newOrderCustomerType::class,
     'allow_add'    => true,
     'by_reference' => false,
))
```

See if that works.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. I tried adding and removing various options and still nothing...